# Deploy to weblogic

Tags: java, excel, apache, tomcat

I'm deploying my war file to `Oracle Weblogic Application 12c`. 
This war file, it's running OK on `apache tomcat 8`.
However, when I deploy it to `Weblogic`, I get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller

I use `Apache POI` to read the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility is run time version of mentioned class differs from version at compile time. You need to check whether you have multiple versions of this class in the classpath.Could you please check for existence of multiple jars containing this class.May be one inside the lib folder of server and another inside your application under lib folder.You need this jar just inside lib folder of your application.